# Родительный падеж в контексте (см.) будет ли воспринят адекватно?

Tags: падежи

> И каким значимым совпадением кажется факт, что свой шедевр фресковой живописи Филиппино создаст напротив могилы Фра Беато Анджелико. Удивительного художника. Воистину блаженного брата. **Признанного католичеством небесного покровителя** всех на свете художников. И учителя Филиппо Липпи. Словно в искупление...

Уже занесла руку править над *небесным покровителем*... да одумалась: без подсказки ни-ни.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Галя, а чем родительный не понравился? Это же парцелляция, где все части - приложения в род.пад.: напротив могилы (кого?)Фра Беато Анджелико. (кого?)Удивительного **художника**. (кого?)Воистину блаженного **брата**. (кого?)...небесного **покровителя** (какого?) признанного католичеством. (и ещё кого?) И **учителя** Филиппо Липпи.

А вариант правки - творительный падеж?  *Признанного католичеством **небесным покровителем** всех на свете художников* Но тогда нарушится **параллелизм** конструкции, а здесь именно он важен.

По-моему, родительный падеж на месте.

Answer (score 2):

С них, католиков, станется, конечно. Но вполне достойно будет и «Признанного католиками небесного наставника всякого художника».

Фразой «И учителя Филиппо Липпи», поскольку характер личности идёт *по нарастающей*, нужно начать череду родительных: «Филиппино создаст напротив могилы учителя своего отца Филиппо Липпи, — самого Фра Анджелико. Художника удивительного...».